# Windows Sharepoint Service (WSS) 3.0 search Issue

Tags: sharepoint

Based on this http://servergrrl.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-use-wss-30-to-search-more-than.html blog, I've created a domain account for testing and sets the permission at the side level as well as Document Library to allow specific user (DOMAIN/TestUser1) allow accessing this folder.

Now, it's interesting that the user can see the document by drilling though BUT it won't be able to search and the document couldn't find it. But if I tested with the site owner (both primary and secondary), it works nicely.

What did I do wrong then? It must be related on permission but I cound't work out what it is.

BTW ... I am using WSS not MOSS 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under `List Settings` -> `Advanced Settings`  Have you allowed the items to be searchable?

> Allow items from this list to appear
>   in search results?

Comment: Hi Shoban. I couldn't find the setting that you mentioned. Is it under the site setting or ducument library setting?

Comment: Actually I found that, "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" is set as Yes already. So any other ideas?

Comment: Are you able to check "search index" or crawled content in central administration?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case the problem was because search engine was searching in a domain different that it should have. It was a mapping problem. After configuring alternate access mapping the problem disappeared. Check it out: http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx